# Incomprehensible speed lowered situation

Tags: qgis

I recently started to learn QGIS system and used quite well to develop a project.
I wanted to have faster outputs so I bought a new desktop.

The old one specification is like this:

- CPU intel i5-7400 CPU @ 3Ghz
- 8GB RAM
- No extentional VGA

and new one is like this:

- CPU AMD Ryzen 9 3900 (12 core, 24 threads)
- 64GB RAM
- VGA GeForce RTX2080 Ti

Yes, I put much money to see higher performance but it is totally slower than before for making even simple joining by location.

Is there any hint of reason?

Other environments are same like
Windows 10 / QGIS 3.8 / sets all the settings and options between old and new one.

I can't understand...

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. What kind of data you have ? all your data in shape files or in database ? Also let us know your objective that you want to achieve in QGIS

Comment: yes, grid.shp (in points 50m x 50m, 242000 points) and polygons.shp(boundary shape) and wanted  to make attributes joined into grids.
and did join by location.

Comment: The QGIS version you use now and the version you used then are the same? I have experienced some performance issues when I update from QGIS 2.18 to QGIS 3.6 (the same project I used is taking much more time to load)

Comment: yes, before and after is on QGIS 3.8 latetest version.
also I am trying same works on each versions 
I think hardware or software setting has problem.
when it processes algorithm cpu usage is less than 10%
I check Using multiple threads on rendering but it is not on rendering but processing simple algorithm.

Is there any possiblity about cpu virtualizations or performance related to power setting....?
or is it too much new cpu product....?

Comment: @dolgil2 - In `Settings > Options > Accelaration`, there is an option to increase performance of core algorithms and rendering if you have a recognised OpenCL device. **Note: this is experimental and may crash QGIS**. Another option is to create a _virtual layer_ or use PostGIS for large datasets.

Comment: @joseph thanks That is my 2nd curiousity. I tried to take that option but I couldn't check and select it, it doesnt recognize opencl, I installed CUDA and opencl for gpu also but it doesn't recognize... 
i guess somehow i made mistake like didn't properly add a library or, but that is next problem coz before i changed pc, never used acceleration options.. anyways.... 
i guess for some reason qgis is not able to use full cores of cpu.
can't find the way to raise usage of cpu..

Comment: Your system configuration details don't mention the disk access protocol and rotational speed. GIS is I/O bound; no amount of RAM can offset a sluggish disk. This is a discussion topic, but GIS SE is not a discussion site. While we have [chat], it has a minimum reputation requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a specialist on these matter but after some internet reading I gather that :

- Processing mostly (?) use a single one Core. (so it's possible that one core of your
  new processor is less efficient than one core from your old
  processor, even if the total processing power is far superior)
- Processing doesn't use the GPU so any upgrade in that area is
  worthless.
- One of the main factor for speed is the time spend to read an write
  data so getting faster hard drive / faster memory / faster network...
  is often the best way to better performance

Comment: now i am able to understand. Thank you so much! and sorry for making not so much related questions on unsuitable place. Thank you again